# Hide the number that my phone is dialing?

Tags: android, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to hide the number that is called from an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969881/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-number-that-is-called-from-an-app)
>   [How to hide phone number when calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934562/ios-how-to-hide-phone-number-when-calling)
>   [Can I programmatically place an anonymous phone call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526007/can-i-programmatically-place-an-anonymous-phone-call)

When I dial a number using android it display the number or the name of the person I am dialing, is there anyway to hide that number from the display? in the other word user does not see which number is dialing?